# Android Studio cannot find Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I'm trying to get the Android P preview setup, and in the process I am upgrading all my dependencies, but it gets mad when Firebase and Google Play Services don't match versions. (It wont build). The latest version of Google Play Services is 15.0.1 as denoted [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). The latest version of Firebase is version 16.0.0, according to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). So I figured I should use 15.0.1 for all of them. However Android Studio can't seem to resolve any version of Firebase. It always gives me an error like this:

[image]

It gives the same error for any version I give it.

Here are my dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
```

Comment: Jinkies, I forgot my reading glasses. Can you add the error as text instead of an image?

Comment: @sadelbrid add your gradle file

Comment: Since version 15, the Play Services and Firebase SDKs will not all be on the same version.  Scroll down on that page of documentation you linked, and you will see the current versions of each library.

Comment: @sadelbrid you should update firebase-core and use the latest google-services, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try to update firebase like below:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Also make sure that you use latest google service:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I still don't understand why it can't resolve firebase-ads:16.0.0... leaving ads at 15.0.1 and making your changes got it working though

Comment: as Doug said since version 15 play services and firebase sdks will not be in the same version. shall you accept my answer too? thanks you a lot, good coding

Comment: @sadelbrid could you please accept my answer too? thank you have a nice day coding!

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) you are linked to you can find annotation

> // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>
> // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle

```
allprojects {
// ...
repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `firebase-core` library wasn't released at version 15.0.1. You can see via http://maven.google.com that you should use either 15.0.2 or 16.0.0 (my suggestion is to always use 16+ libraries when they exist b/c we're removing version ranges from the POM files (therefore, you'll go back to hermetic builds). The May 23rd entry of our release notes goes into more details, if needed. (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

The assumption that all of the libraries should be used at the same version is no longer valid as of versions 15.0.0 and greater. Libraries will continue to release independently and with ever-diverging version numbers (following a SemVer.org scheme).